# getting server response with react-dropzone-uploader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

How can I get server response with [react-dropzone-uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start).
I have been working with it, I am trying to find a way of receiving response from a nodejs backend to a react frontend after file has been uploaded or failed.

frontend(react):

```
const getUploadParams = (file) => {

        return {url: uploadUrl, headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`}}
    }

    const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, remove }, status) => {
        if (status === 'done') {
            notify(`${meta.name} uploaded!`)
            remove()
        } else if (status === 'aborted') {
            notify_error(`${meta.name}, Upload failed...`)
        }
    }
```

Backend uploads to Google Cloud Storage, so on success, I want to send a reponse to the frontend to be able to notify the user status of their file upload

backend (nodejs):

```
bucket.upload(file.path, {
                                public: true,
                                destination: set_user_folder + file.name,
                                resumable: true,
                            }, function (err, file, apiResponse) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return res.status(200).send({
                                        message: err,
                                        type: "error"
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    console.log(apiResponse);
                                    return res.status(200).send({
                                        message: "File Uploaded",
                                        type: "success"
                                    });
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I am looking for the same solution to parse a custom response. However, if you have a callback defined for the onChangeStatus event, there is an argument named "status". 


This argument represents the upload status of the file. The value will be a string that is updated when different points of the upload are completed. When the file has successfully been uploaded, the final status value will be "done". There is also a failure status. 


Here in the documentation, you can see all the possible change status values.
https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/props

Answer (score 3):

You can get the server response from `handleChangeStatus` like this:

```
const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, file, xhr}, status) => {
        if (status === 'done'){
            let response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        }  
};
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on non-200 responses (eg `status === "error_upload"`), which is limiting - xhr.response is an empty string, despite the server returning json in my case

Comment: I tried this on codesandbox but it gives an error `xhr is undefined`. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-river-pfzk5z?file=/src/App.js